# MSVC2013 gets confused over calling convention of ctor

Tags: visual-c++, linker, static-libraries

I've compiled `ns::Foo::Foo` int a static lib using `/Gd` and am trying to use it from an another static lib that's also compiled using `/Gd`.

The first library contains `public: __thiscall ns::Foo::Foo(void))` which seems to be correct, given that [the documentation for `/Gd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46t77ak2.aspx) states that the calling convention for members is `__stdcall`.

When linking the excutable, it fails because there's an unresolvable external for `public: __cdecl ns::Foo::Foo(void))` in the second library despite building everything with `/Gd`. I haven't used any `#pragma` to change the calling convention, either.

Why does MSVC++ fail to use the `__stdcall` calling convention on import, and how do I fix it?

64 bits build, BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the 64 bit build. This build was created from the 32 bit build, but MSVC does not change the library dependency in the process. As a result, the linker tried to link 32 bits function bodies into a 64 bit build. As the member function calling conventions differ, the first check to fail is the name lookup. The linker never gets to a point where it checks if its inputs are all 64 bits.

The fix was to manually update the library dependency; the 64 bit build of the first library did contain the right `ns::Foo::Foo`.